# Python: How can I evaluate an f-string after it is created

Tags: python, f-string

I'd like to evaluate an f-string that I have queried from a database. This string uses a variable I have defined before calling the string.

```
def get_name():
    name = "Ben"

    # from database (the value within the text field I call "name_question" in postgresql says: "My name is {name}")
    name_phrase = DB.objects.get(phrases=name_question)
    
    print(f'{name_phrase}')
```

At the moment my output is:
"My name is {name}"

But I would like it to be
"My name is Ben"

I have tried various ways of nesting, with ''' and " as well as `ast.literal_eval` but cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: How come `name_phrase` is used before initialization? Look at the parameter of the get function call.

Comment: @Balaji-Ambresh , thanks for pointing this out, I amended it. However, it was more of a pseudo code to support the question "how to evaluate f-strings pulled from a database". I should have reviewed that part first, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
print(name_phrase.format(name=name))
```

There is no special function for *evaluating* an `f-string` after it is created so you should use `str.format`.

Comment: Thanks, that did it, although I am a bit disappointed that f-strings cannot be "chained" in such way as I first intended.